# Unable to install rpcbind on Ubuntu 19.10. E: Failed to fetch error

Tags: ubuntu, apt, system-installation, vmware

I'm trying to make an application using `rpc middleware` and I had to install `rpcbind` but then I keep running to an issue:

```
  Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libtirpc-common libtirpc3
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libtirpc-common libtirpc3 rpcbind
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 146 not upgraded.
Need to get 142 kB of archives.
After this operation, 445 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Ign:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan/main amd64 libtirpc-common all 1.1.4-0.4
Err:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan/main amd64 libtirpc3 amd64 1.1.4-0.4
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
Err:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan/main amd64 rpcbind amd64 1.2.5-6
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
Err:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan/main amd64 libtirpc-common all 1.1.4-0.4
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libt/libtirpc/libtirpc-common_1.1.4-0.4_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libt/libtirpc/libtirpc3_1.1.4-0.4_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/r/rpcbind/rpcbind_1.2.5-6_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

When I type `df -h`, I get this:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            953M     0  953M   0% /dev
tmpfs           196M  1.5M  195M   1% /run
/dev/sda1        20G  7.5G   12G  41% /
tmpfs           980M   15M  965M   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           980M     0  980M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0      384K  384K     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/570
/dev/loop3      1.0M  1.0M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/100
/dev/loop1      157M  157M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/110
/dev/loop2       65M   65M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1514
/dev/loop5       98M   98M     0 100% /snap/core/10577
/dev/loop4      218M  218M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/60
/dev/loop7       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/1944
/dev/loop6       90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/8268
/dev/loop9       15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/375
/dev/loop8      163M  163M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/145
/dev/loop10      55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1754
/dev/loop13     4.3M  4.3M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/544
/dev/loop11     2.5M  2.5M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/826
/dev/loop12     1.0M  1.0M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/81
/dev/loop14      45M   45M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1440
tmpfs           196M   32K  196M   1% /run/user/1000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 19.10 is an EOL Ubuntu release. It is recommended to upgrade your distribution.

To continue using an EOL release, you need to adjust your `/etc/apt/sources.list` by replacing the URLs with `http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/`, then run:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

Comment: I'll try it out thanks

Comment: If i install Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS will it work?

Comment: @RouaRouatbi Yes it will work, but before upgrading, please try my answer, if it work ,it will be used by peoples who have a similar problem.

Comment: It workeddd thank youu

Comment: @RouaRouatbi Do not forget to mark my answer as accepted. Thank you.